# Encoding.ASCII VS Encoding.UTF8 Bug

Tags: http, unicode, utf-8, ascii, utf-16

World! I'm writing simple HTML server using .Net Framework 4 **System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient**.

I have HTML in **StringBuilder html**, wich contains some text. For example:

```
<div id="RequestText">

    GET / HTTP/1.1<br/>Host: localhost:90<br/>Connection: keep-alive<br/>Cache-Control: max-age=0<br/>User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11<br/>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<br/>Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch<br/>Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4<br/>Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

</div>
```

The text can be various. When i send a response to client

```
private static void SendResponseToClient(NetworkStream clientStream, StringBuilder html)
    {
        String data = _htmlHeader + html.Length.ToString() + "\n\n" + html; // The "data" is OK!
        Byte[] buffer;
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data); // !UTF8
        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

I use Google Chrome and some parts are lost in the text of displayed page in case with **Encoding.UTF8**. The ending "indows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" is cut. The rest of HTML text after lost part is still in place. If i use **Encoding.ASCII**, everything is ok. Any ideas of the **reasons**?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the limited code you have shown, this is just a guess, but your use of `html.Length.ToString()` suggests to me that your `_htmlHeader` variable contains HTTP headers ending with the `Content-Length` header, and `html.Length.ToString()` is being used to complete that header.  If this is true, then you are sending the wrong `Length` value to the client, so it ends up reading the wrong number of bytes from the socket on its end.  The `Content-Length` header specifies **the number of bytes that are being sent**.  You are setting the `Content-Length` to **the number of UTF-16 encoded characters** that are in the `StringBuilder` when you should be setting it to **the number of UTF-8 encoded bytes** that you are sending instead.

Try this:

```
private static void SendResponseToClient(NetworkStream clientStream, StringBuilder html)
{
    Byte[] html_buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html.ToString());

    // HTTP does not support non-ASCII characters in headers.
    Byte[] http_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_htmlHeader + html_buffer.Length.ToString() + "\n\n");

    clientStream.Write(http_buffer, 0, http_buffer.Length);
    clientStream.Write(html_buffer, 0, html_buffer.Length);
}
```

And of course, make sure that `_htmlHeader` includes a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header to make sure the client handles the UTF-8 encoded HTML correctly.

Comment: Thnx! Hope this helps. I try it tomorrow, and write the results.

Comment: Unfortunately "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing... but maybe UTF-8 encoding is using more bytes to encode your text than ASCII (probably some characters get encoded in a two-byte manner while ASCII just use a ? or something like that for them) and thus the max length of the message is surpassed?

Comment: If i understood you correctly, in this case the whole rest part of message should be lost, but in my case the rest of text is still present.

Comment: Oh I see... I'd understood that text get cut awhole